# How to publish web application project?

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I want to publish my project on internet through my paid web 
, but they doesn't support JSP pages and glassfish.

So is there's any way to publish it?

Comment: Sorry then. not possible.

Comment: Only few providers offer glasfish (full JEE). Most (having Java in his offers) offer servlet containers (Jetty / Tomcat). But this offer is significantly narrow than PHP

Answer (score 1):

**There are different ways to deploy your build to web servers according to the server. In this situation you telling that you are using glassfish server. It allows three different methods as follows.**

**1. Using admin console**

First thing you should be able to access admin console which is **`http://localhost:4848`**. Follow the link below the step by step guide to deploy from oracle help.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/ghgjn/index.html

**2. Using command line**

You should be able to access command line with `asadmin` commands.  Use following guide to deploy using command line.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/ghgjj/index.html

**3. Deploying an Application Automatically**

You can deploy applications automatically by placing them in the as-install/domains/domain-name/autodeploy directory, where domain-name is the name of the domain for which you want to configure automatic deployment. Follow the link below to step by step guide.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/ghgmi/index.html